# Pass class only given methods

Tags: php, oop

The `$bar` object will have access to all of `foo`'s methods and properties.

Instead, can I give `$bar` only access to one of `foo`'s methods such as `letBarUse()`?

```
<?php
class foo
{
    public $bar, $a,$b,$c;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar=new bar($this);
    }
    public function letBarUse(){
        $this->a=$this->b;
    }
    public function dontLetBarUse1(){}
    public function dontLetBarUse2(){}
}

class bar
{
    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo=$foo;
    }
    public function hello(){
        $this->foo->letBarUse(); // Okay
        $this->foo->dontLetBarUse1(); //Not okay
    }
}
```

Comment: Make private the methods you don't want `bar` to see.

Comment: As a special case just for `bar`? Or for *any* consumer of `foo`…?

Comment: @deceze  For a special case just for `bar`.

Comment: Typical case of [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: class foo_bar extends foo
    {
        public function dontLetBarUse1(){
            throw new Exception('dontLetBarUse1');
       }
    }

Comment: @AlmaDo  Yea, I agree, but asking `x` is outside of the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot selectively restrict the callability of methods for specific callers. You should simply hint it through an interface:

```
interface SupportsBars {
    public function letBarUse();
}

class Foo implements SupportsBars { ... }

class Bar {
    public function __construct(SupportsBars $supporter) {
        $this->supporter = $supporter;
    }
}
```

Yes, `Bar` *will* be able to call other methods than `letBarUse`, ***but*** it is not type-safe for it to do so. The fact that you happen to pass in an object which happens to have other methods is irrelevant; `Bar` has declared that it is only interested in a specific interface and it *should not* attempt to call anything else which wasn't declared in the interface.

There's no real need to be any more restrictive than that, since anyone can call anything anyway. Even `protected` and `private` methods can be called if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possiblity that allows you to do exactly that, but it is not classes. Whet you are after are `trait`s. [The official PHP documentation on traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and how you can use only parts of them.

I would assume that you are using PHP version > 5.3 (and you really should by now), since they are 5.4+ feature.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You have to use the 'protected' keyword on that method and 'private' on the others

Comment: That won't let `bar` use any of `foo`'s methods.

Comment: Protected will let him use the one he intends and hide the others. That is what he asked.

Comment: If `foo`'s method is `protected`, then `bar` cannot call it.